# creating a background loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, android-studio, infinite-loop, google-play-games

I'm writing a game program. When the game starts I want the background image to follow each other with an infinite loop. However, with the codes I wrote, the first picture comes and stops. After a while, the second picture comes on the first picture. So I cannot ensure that the pictures follow each other continuously. Could you help?
The code I wrote for this loop looks like this:

```
if (gameState == 1) {

    backgroundX -= 3;
    if (backgroundX < -Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 100) {
        backgroundX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();

    } else {
        backgroundX -= 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a loop, it's a conditional. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: for(int i=0;i<numberOfBackground;i++) {
 if (backgroundX[i] < -badboy.getWidth()) {
  backgroundX[i] = backgroundX[i] + numberOfBackground * distance;
 } else {
  backgroundX[i] = backgroundX[i] - 2 * enemyVelocity;
 }

Comment: When I create a loop in this way, the same thing happens again. After the first picture, it remains constant. The second picture comes upon it. I want the second picture and the first picture will come out. So they move at the same time so that there is continuity.

Comment: I found my mistake. The error I made when specifying the condition caused this situation. I've just corrected. Thank you.